# Define number of decimals returned by Bing Maps query C#

Tags: c#, rest, location, maps, bing-maps

I am signed up for the mscodechallenge.net, and currently doing the Bing Maps challenge. I currently have an issue however getting the correct result.

To pass the included unit test I need to retrieve the coordinates (55.8408508, 12.5594797) (latitude, longitude) for the address "Frydenlunds Alle 6 2950 DK" to PASS the test however my current code returns too few decimals to PASS. My current result is (55.84085, 12,55948). Is it possible to state the number of decimals in the result returned by the Bing Maps API? I have tried using both the query and unstructured URLs available, but with the same result.

My current code and the resulting XML from the service:

C#

```
    public double[] Execute(string addressLine, string postalCode, string countryCode)
    {

        var bingKey = "anonymised";
        var queryUrl = CreateURL(addressLine, countryCode, postalCode, bingKey);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream data = client.OpenRead(queryUrl);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        data.Close();
        reader.Close();

        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result)))
        {
            xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Latitude");
            var lat = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
            xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Longitude");
            var lon = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();

            double[] resultArray = new double[] { lat, lon };

            return resultArray;
        }
    }

    private string CreateURL(string address, string countrycode, string postalcode, string bingKey)
    {
        return string.Format(
            GetUrl(), 
            Uri.EscapeDataString(address), 
            Uri.EscapeDataString(postalcode), 
            Uri.EscapeDataString(countrycode),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(bingKey));
    }

    private string GetUrl()
    {
        //return "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion={2}&postalCode={1}&addressLine={0}&includeNeighborhood=0&maxResults=10&key={3}&output=xml";
        return "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={0}, {1}, {2}&key={3}&output=xml";
    }
```

XML Response from service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
    <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
    <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
    <ResourceSets>
        <ResourceSet>
            <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
            <Resources>
                <Location>
                    <Name>Frydenlunds Allé, 2950 Vedbæk, Denmark</Name>
                    <Point>
                        <Latitude>55.84085</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>12.55948</Longitude>
                    </Point>
                    <BoundingBox>
                        <SouthLatitude>55.83974</SouthLatitude>
                        <WestLongitude>12.55612</WestLongitude>
                        <NorthLatitude>55.84159</NorthLatitude>
                        <EastLongitude>12.56277</EastLongitude>
                    </BoundingBox>
                    <EntityType>RoadBlock</EntityType>
                    <Address>
                        <AddressLine>Frydenlunds Allé</AddressLine>
                        <AdminDistrict>Capital Region</AdminDistrict>
                        <AdminDistrict2>Rudersdal</AdminDistrict2>
                        <CountryRegion>Denmark</CountryRegion>
                        <FormattedAddress>Frydenlunds Allé, 2950 Vedbæk, Denmark</FormattedAddress>
                        <Locality>Vedbæk</Locality>
                        <PostalCode>2950</PostalCode>
                    </Address>
                    <Confidence>Medium</Confidence>
                    <MatchCode>Good</MatchCode>
                    <MatchCode>UpHierarchy</MatchCode>
                    <GeocodePoint>
                        <Latitude>55.84085</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>12.55948</Longitude>
                        <CalculationMethod>InterpolationOffset</CalculationMethod>
                        <UsageType>Display</UsageType>
                    </GeocodePoint>
                    <GeocodePoint>
                        <Latitude>55.84085</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>12.55948</Longitude>
                        <CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod>
                        <UsageType>Route</UsageType>
                    </GeocodePoint>
                </Location>
            </Resources>
        </ResourceSet>
    </ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to have additional coordinates returned. I'm actually surprised that this code challenge is doing something like this as address coordinates can change from time to time. Also, they are using 7 decimal places which is accurate down to 1cm. The Bing Maps REST service is only returning 5 decimal places which has an accuracy of about 1m. The rest of the decimal places are insignificant.

If this code challenge is for a UWP app, then it is possible that the built in geocoder may return more decimal places as it currently uses a different geocoding engine at the moment.

Comment: The challenge is not for an UWP app, but I cannot exclude that they might use the same unit test for multiple challenges. I think I will open a ticket to the mscodechallenge.net team and ask them about this.

Comment: Opening a ticket would be a good idea. If you like you can include my email in the ticket for them to refer to; richbrun at microsoft.com